# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined phaser

Tags: javascript, undefined, phaser-framework

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined?? What is that suppose to mean?

I mean i tried debugging it and all but cant figure out the problem. Help would be really appreciated. Anything you guys need to help figure out this problem, please feel free to ask me. Thank you!

[JSBIN](http://output.jsbin.com/peyadiw)

Here is my code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 550, Phaser.CANVAS, 'gameDiv');

var CountDown = {

    preload: function() {
    },
    update: function() {
    },
    render: function() {
    }
}
var player;
var bullets;
var enemies;
var greenEnemies
var bulletTimer = 0;
var mainState = {

    preload: function() {
        game.load.image('background', 'http://s1.postimg.org/nqynk9tkv/starfield.png')
        game.load.image('player', 'http://s28.postimg.org/9qdf4xrfx/145103252914234.gif')
        game.load.image('bullet', 'http://s9.postimg.org/z2bptetxn/bullet.png');
        game.load.image('green', 'http://s28.postimg.org/kpmq4byt5/enemy_green.png')
    },

    create: function() {
        this.backgroundImg = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 500, 550, 'background')
        player = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, 500, 'player')
        player.anchor.setTo(0.5)
        player.scale.setTo(0.25)
        game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
        game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
        this.game.inputEnabled = true;
        this.game.input.useHandCursor = true;
        player.body.maxVelocity.setTo(400, 400)
        player.body.drag.setTo(400, 400)

        //  The baddies!
    greenEnemies = game.add.group();
    greenEnemies.enableBody = true;
    greenEnemies.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
    greenEnemies.createMultiple(5, 'green');
    greenEnemies.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
    greenEnemies.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
    greenEnemies.setAll('scale.x', 0.5);
    greenEnemies.setAll('scale.y', 0.5);
    greenEnemies.setAll('angle', 180);
    greenEnemies.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    greenEnemies.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);

    this.launchGreenEnemy();

        bullets = game.add.group();
        bullets.enableBody = true;
        bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
        bullets.createMultiple(30, 'bullet');
        bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
        bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 1);
        bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
        bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);

        this.cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        this.fireButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR)
    },

    update: function() {
        this.backgroundImg.tilePosition.y += 2;
        player.body.acceleration.x = 0;
        if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
            player.body.acceleration.x -= 600;


        } else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
            player.body.acceleration.x += 600;
        }

        if (this.fireButton.isDown) {
            //Grab first bullet from the pool

            if (game.time.now > bulletTimer) {
                var bullet = bullets.getFirstExists(false);
                if (bullet) {
                    bullet.reset(player.x, player.y + 8);
                    //Getting it up
                    bullet.body.velocity.y = -400;
                    bulletTimer = game.time.now + 250;
                }
            }
        }
    },

    launchGreenEnemy: function(){

    var MIN_ENEMY_SPACING = 300;
    var MAX_ENEMY_SPACING = 3000;
    var ENEMY_SPEED = 300;

    var enemy = greenEnemies.getFirstExists(false);
    if (enemy) {
        enemy.reset(game.rnd.integerInRange(0, game.width), -20);
        enemy.body.velocity.x = game.rnd.integerInRange(-300, 300);
        enemy.body.velocity.y = ENEMY_SPEED;
        enemy.body.drag.x = 100;
    }

    //  Send another enemy soon
    game.time.events.add(game.rnd.integerInRange(300, 3000), this.launchGreenEnemy);
    },

    // Restart the game
    platformsCreate: function() {

    }
};

var Menu = {
    preload: function() {
    },
    create: function() {
    },
    update: function() {
    },
    render: function() {
    },
    start: function() {
    }
};

var Game_Over = {
    preload: function() {
    },
    create: function() {
    },
    update: function() {
    },
    render: function() {
    },
    onDown: function() {
    }
};
// Add and start the 'main' state to start the game
game.state.add('CountDown', CountDown)
game.state.add('main', mainState);
game.state.add('Menu', Menu);
game.state.add('Game_Over', Game_Over);
game.state.start('main');
```

Comment: It means that somewhere in your code there's something like `whatever.apply`, and `whatever` is `undefined`. That is, instead of `whatever` being a reference to an object, it's not.

Comment: I never used the apply method. Thats why im so confused... I think its where in the game.events.add method but not sure.

Comment: I don't see `apply` mentioned anywhere in your code; it could be in a library you're using, meaning that you're invoking some library API in a way the library doesn't expect. You should be able to use a non-minified version of the library along with the browser's debug tools to figure out where in your code that's happening.

Comment: I included a JSBin format, take a look at that. Maybe it will help

Comment: It looks like something in that Phaser code expects there to be a "callback" property on elements in some data structure. I'm totally unfamiliar with that code however so I don't really know what much of it means.

Comment: Oh so you cant help me? :-( .

Comment: I got the anwser @Pointy Posted it for others with same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined with phaser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470153/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined-with-phaser)

Comment: Its not, this is fiffrent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm posting this anwser to help others who are having the same issue.

Basically I looked up the syntax and it had three arguments.

Before, my code was:

```
game.time.events.add(game.rnd.integerInRange(300, 3000), this.launchGreenEnemy);
```

It needed the this parameter at the end to point at that object so I had to put this at the end like this:

```
game.time.events.add(game.rnd.integerInRange(300, 3000), this.launchGreenEnemy, this);
                                                                              ^^^^^^
```

Comment: In my case it wasn't the context parameter but the event handler that I had a typo in which caused this. Thanks.